# Compass on Win using relative paths outside of Compass project dir

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I was using Sass on an existing site and decided to get Compass up and running on Win7x64. Ruby, HAML, Compass all installed fine (afaik).

I have a project at `c:\project` with a static files served out of `c:\project\static` with a directory structure that **has to stay the same**. I went into `c:\project\static` and ran this:

```
compass create css-compass
```

This resulted in the following dir structure

```
c:\project\static\css (previously existed; output css)
c:\project\static\css-sass (previously existed; source css)
c:\project\static\css-compass (the new compass dir created by compass)
```

And here is my config.rb:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "..\\css"
sass_dir = "..\\css-sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

When I go to `c:\project\static` and run `compass watch compass-css`, I get the following error:

> Nothing to compile. If you're trying
>   to start a new project, you have left
>   off the directory argument. Run
>   "compass -h" to get help.

However, if I create symlinks inside `c:\project\static\css-compass` from `css->..\css` and `css-sass => ..\css-sass` then everything works just fine.

What the what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***facepalm***

Apparently you need to set `relative_assets = true` in your config.rb file. Why this isn't the default is beyond me. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

im late :-)

You can also use relative Path's in `project_path`

**Example**

```
project_path    = "../src/main/webapp/"
```

More Details in this Answer: [Can't make grunt-contrib-compass work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544779/cant-make-grunt-contrib-compass-work/20547731#20547731)