# Can't make grunt-contrib-compass work

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass

So I have the following situation.
When I'm using compass just from CLI it just works and does exactly what's required. I'm running `compass compile` from the same folder where `config.rb` file is located (in `styles` folder). It also contains also `sass` and `css` directories.
Here's my `config.rb` file:

```
project_path = '.'
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "../../data/images"
javascripts_dir = "../scripts"

output_style = :compressed
environment = :development
relative_assets = true
```

When I'm trying to use `grunt` for this I use the following configuration in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
compass: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            basePath: 'app/src/styles',
            config: 'app/src/styles/config.rb'
        }
    }
}
```

The `app` folder and `Gruntfile.js` are located at the same level. 
When I'm running `grunt compass` I see the following output:

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help.

Done, without errors.
```

If I try to specify all the options directly like:

```
compass: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            basePath: 'app/src/styles',
            sassDir: 'app/src/styles/sass',
            cssDir: 'app/src/styles/css',
            imagesDir: 'app/data/images'
        }
    }
}
```

It does the job, but the `.sass-cache` folder is created at the level of `Gruntfile.js`.
So I guess there's some problem with `basePath` option of the configuration.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

**EDIT**:
The only way, I managed to make it work, as intended is moving `config.rb` file to the level of `Gruntfile.js`, and specifying the following options in it:

```
project_path = 'app/src/styles'
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "../../data/images"
javascripts_dir = "../scripts"

output_style = :compressed
environment = :development
relative_assets = true
```

Also I removed all of the options from the 'Gruntfile.js`, which regard to this task. Still not sure, what's going on here.

Comment: http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/css/image-url/

Answer (score 3):

Try not setting the basePath in the Grunt config, i.e:

```
compass: {
   compile: {
     options: {
        basePath: 'app/src/styles',
        config: 'app/src/styles/config.rb'
    }
  }
}
```

Turn into:

```
compass: {
       compile: {
         options: {
            config: 'app/src/styles/config.rb'
        }
      }
    }
```

And also run your `Grunt Compass` with the --verbose switch (`grunt compass --verbose`) to see what files grunt is trying to process.

Notice that any setting you add to your options in the Grunt file will override (or extend) the settings in your config.rb file.

Check out this page: [`https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) to see more info about grunt-contrib-compass. they have info about all the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a different Base Path for your Project than your config.rb, you can set the Path in config.rb (even relative)

**Example config.rb**

```
project_path    = "../src/main/webapp/"
http_path       = "./"
css_dir         = "css"
sass_dir        = "../library"
images_dir      = "assets/images"
fonts_dir       = "assets/fonts"
javascripts_dir = "assets/js"

...

relative_assets = true
```

**Example SCSS**

```
.stylesheet-url {
  content:stylesheet-url("style.css");
}

.font-url {
  content:font-url("font.woff");
}

.image-url {
  content:image-url("image.png");
}

.generated-image-url {
  content:generated-image-url("image2.png");
}
```

**Example CSS**

```
.stylesheet-url {
  content: url('style.css');
}

.font-url {
  content: url('../assets/fonts/font.woff');
}

.image-url {
  content: url('../assets/images/image.png');
}

.generated-image-url {
  content: url('../assets/images/image2.png');
}
```

We run Compass 0.12.latest on Win7 x64